# origin/master is n ahead of upstream/master but HEADS are same

Tags: git

I pulled from upstream master and pushed into origin master (in GitHub). In Github says **This branch is 2624 commits ahead of <upstream>:master**.

`sdiff <(git log --oneline upstream/master) <(git log --oneline master)` goes:

```
                                                              > a6ef172176 WIP
3153b6c723 [ci skip] Merge PR 29662                             3153b6c723 [ci skip] Merge PR 29662
46e2d4447a [ci skip] Merge PR 29661                             46e2d4447a [ci skip] Merge PR 29661
01ad9a87d5 [ci skip] Merge PR 29654                             01ad9a87d5 [ci skip] Merge PR 29654
543741b864 [ci skip] Merge PR 29582                             543741b864 [ci skip] Merge PR 29582
b57847baec Update gnuvid to 2.3 (#29657)                        b57847baec Update gnuvid to 2.3 (#29657)
6fe58002a6 [ci skip] Merge PR 29656                             6fe58002a6 [ci skip] Merge PR 29656
51d39d12c9 Update mothur to 1.45.3. (#29648)                    51d39d12c9 Update mothur to 1.45.3. (#29648)
b3b20187a2 [ci skip] Merge PR 29641                             b3b20187a2 [ci skip] Merge PR 29641
cd72c9b0df [ci skip] Merge PR 29649                             cd72c9b0df [ci skip] Merge PR 29649
f914b4c668 Clair3 version update to v0.1.5 (#29645)             f914b4c668 Clair3 version update to v0.1.5 (#29645)
d65e364630 [ci skip] Merge PR 29594                             d65e364630 [ci skip] Merge PR 29594
0cda28246e Update meta.yaml (#29636)                            0cda28246e Update meta.yaml (#29636)
ee067084bc Update mosdepth to 0.3.2 (#29639)                    ee067084bc Update mosdepth to 0.3.2 (#29639)
48cef95d0a Update phispy to 4.2.19 (#29403)                     48cef95d0a Update phispy to 4.2.19 (#29403)
9b8b34a9ff [ci skip] Merge PR 29629                             9b8b34a9ff [ci skip] Merge PR 29629
1e1bb9694f [ci skip] Merge PR 29630                             1e1bb9694f [ci skip] Merge PR 29630
bce65d59ac [ci skip] Merge PR 29524                             bce65d59ac [ci skip] Merge PR 29524
81537fe92f [ci skip] Merge PR 29614                             81537fe92f [ci skip] Merge PR 29614
2ab97905f7 [ci skip] Merge PR 29628                             2ab97905f7 [ci skip] Merge PR 29628
f97da5b847 metaplatanus (#29593)                                f97da5b847 metaplatanus (#29593)
45c2295cb7 [ci skip] Merge PR 29627                             45c2295cb7 [ci skip] Merge PR 29627
5a25fbd7b3 Update sourmash to 4.2.1 (#29622)                    5a25fbd7b3 Update sourmash to 4.2.1 (#29622)
...
```

where the commit `WIP` is a workaround that I tried and not the problem.
The log keeps going and down I found 2624 differences like these 3:

```
                                                      > 03f566bd3c 2nd try
                                                      > 1b1da3bfc8 Merge branch 'bioconda:master' into master
                                                      > 3c9a3fd0d1 updated tasmanian-mismatch
```

If I open a PR will I have to deal with these differences? How can I sync with upstream before I open the PR.

Thank you!

Comment: What's the problem? As you say, the heads are identical. So you are "in sync." If you branch from 3153b6c723 and add commits and make a PR to merge into upstream master, the merge base is 3153b6c723.

Comment: @matt And the fact that histories are different will not cause problems? Why can't I get that branches are `up to date`?

Comment: When you do a merge, Git does not care about the histories beyond the merge base. As for getting an "up to date" status, you will never have that (unless you start a new fork) so stop worrying about it.

Comment: FWIW : try running `git log --oneline --graph master upstream/master`. The `--graph` option is precious to make sense of how commits are related, and you can have the combined view of both branches in one single output. Add `--decorate` if your git version doesn't show the names of the branches on the graph by default.